# Javafx - Get RGB Value from Node's Color Fill

Tags: java, colors, javafx, paint, rgb

In my javafx app, I create a circle and then allow the user to color it in...

```
Circle circle = new Circle();
circle.setFill(colorPicker.getValue());
```

Then I need to later fetch the color that the circle is and get the RGB values into hex form (#FFFFFF)

```
circle.getFill(); //returns a Paint object
```

How do I get the fill in RGB hex form??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
Color c = (Color) circle.getFill();
String hex = String.format( "#%02X%02X%02X",
            (int)( c.getRed() * 255 ),
            (int)( c.getGreen() * 255 ),
            (int)( c.getBlue() * 255 ) );
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: How can you guarantee that the fill really is a `Color` though?